# conversion from a 8 bit depth image to a 24 bit depth image

Tags: java

when i am trying to read 8 bit depth file using Buffered Image but getting null without any error and i am loading jpeg file.

```
sf = new File("mandate_00028_01.jpeg")
image = ImageIO.read(sf);
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify the full path to your image file like `c:\users\neealm\pictures\mandate_00028_01.jpeg`? Your code currently looks for the image relative to the execution location. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: yes i am using full path only like D:/Neelam/scaned mandates/mandate_00028_01.jpeg

Comment: and what's the output of `sf.exists()` after instantiating it with `sf = new File("mandate_00028_01.jpeg")`?

Comment: and something like this? `URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "mandate_00028_01.jpeg");  
image = ImageIO.read(url);`

Comment: See the Javadoc of `ImageIO.read`:"Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. **If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.**". It doesn't mean that your file wasn't found - you would get an exception in that case. It means that your JVM doesn't have a reader configured for this type of image file.

Comment: See what value `sf.getAbsolutePath()` has.  You might be surprised.